# Web Fragment not Full Fill

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How can I load a web view full Fill into a fragment?

FragmentActivity.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web, group, false);
    wb = ((WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewApp));
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    pg = ((ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2));
    wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wb.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wb.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wb.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wb.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    wb.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView paramAnonymousWebView, int paramAnonymousInt)
        {
            web.this.pg.setVisibility(0);
            web.this.pg.setProgress(paramAnonymousInt);
            if (paramAnonymousInt == 100) {
                web.this.pg.setVisibility(8);
            }
        }
    });
    this.pg.setVisibility(0);
    this.wb.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    return rootView;
}
```

Web.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffe0b2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />
<WebView
    android:id="@id/webViewApp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mxhj.png)
Thanks :))

Comment: Cleaned up the formatting of the source code so that it appears in proper blocks and enabled the link to your first screenshot.

Comment: does not work still it http://i.stack.imgur.com/7mxhj.png, wrong my code ?

Comment: My question may be complete at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559876/how-webview-inside-fragment-navigationdrawer-can-fill-in-fragment ,

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to simplify your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <WebView
        android:id="@id/webViewApp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/progressBar2"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And** make sure, that in your Activities' layout `Fragment`'s Container is `below` Toolbar, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/action_bar_height"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My question may be complete at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559876/how-webview-inside-fragment-navigationdrawer-can-fill-in-fragment ,